# pdfkit is working on python2 but it's not working in python3

Tags: python-3.x

import pdfkit

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "`<stdin>`", line 1, in `<module>` ImportError: No module named 'pdfkit'

when i use pdfkit in python2 then it works fine, but if i use in python3 it gives the above error

Comment: How did you install pdfkit for Python 3?

Comment: @Evert Sudo pip install pdfkit

Comment: How did you install it for Python 2?

Comment: i install only one time, Can you tell me how it install for python3

Comment: @Evert Thanks Now it's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages for Python 2 and Python 3 are completely separate. You have to install any package for both Python versions separately. Try:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pdfkit
```